# Assign values from pandas.quantile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just try to get the quantiles of a dataframe asigned on to an other dataframe like:

`dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7])`

the result is 

`0      NaN
...
5758   NaN
Name: pc, Length: 5759, dtype: float64`

any idea why the `dataframe['row']` got plenty of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected, because different indices, so no align `Series` created by `quantile` with original `DataFrame` and get `NaN`s:

```
#indices 0,1,2...6
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'row':[2,0,8,1,7,4,5]})
print (dataframe)
   row
0    2
1    0
2    8
3    1
4    7
5    4
6    5

#indices 0.1, 0.5, 0.7
print (dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]))
0.1    0.6
0.5    4.0
0.7    5.4
Name: row, dtype: float64

#not align
dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7])
print (dataframe)
   row  pc
0    2 NaN
1    0 NaN
2    8 NaN
3    1 NaN
4    7 NaN
5    4 NaN
6    5 NaN
```

If want create DataFrame of `quantile` add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df)
     a    b
0  0.1  0.6
1  0.5  4.0
2  0.7  5.4
```

---

But if some indices are same (I think it is not what you want, only for better explanation):

Add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for default indices `0,1,2`:

```
print (dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).reset_index(drop=True))
0    0.6
1    4.0
2    5.4
Name: row, dtype: float64
```

First 3 rows are aligned, because same indices `0,1,2` in `Series` and `DataFrame`:

```
dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (dataframe)
   row   pc
0    2  0.6
1    0  4.0
2    8  5.4
3    1  NaN
4    7  NaN
5    4  NaN
6    5  NaN
```

EDIT:
For multiple columns need [`DataFrame.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html), it also exclude non numeric columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

df1 = df.quantile([.1,.2,.3,.4])
print (df1)
       B    C    D    E
0.1  4.0  2.5  0.5  2.5
0.2  4.0  3.0  1.0  3.0
0.3  4.0  3.5  1.0  3.5
0.4  4.0  4.0  1.0  4.0
```

Comment: great thank you for this answer!
Now i get an output but still a lot of NaN's

What i want is an output which outputs only as many Collums as the input for `.percentile()` was.

So for `.percentile([.1,.2,.3,.4])` i expect only 4 Collums

When is use `dataframe['row'] = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).reset_index(drop=True)`

i get 

```0       0.009876
1       0.012500
2       0.012125
3       0.013446
4       0.013752
5            NaN
.....
5758         NaN
Name: pc, Length: 5759, dtype: float64```

Comment: You are welcome! Do you wand percentile for multiple columns? Checl last edit.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `dataframe['row'] = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).reset_index(drop=True) i get 0 0.009876 1 0.012500 2 0.012125 3 0.013446 4 0.013752 5 NaN ..... 5758 NaN ` - it is expected output and dont use it ;) you need `df = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')`

Comment: But if want new columns filled by same values `df1 = dataframe.join(dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).to_frame().T.rename({'row':0})).ffill()`

Comment: ok thanks a lot! 
Now when i use `dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')`

i get
`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

When i use:
`dataframe['pc'] = dataframe.join(dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).to_frame().T.rename({'row':0})).ffill()`

i get:
`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 25, placement implies 1`

Comment: But there is one big difference, you need always assign to variable, not to new column. So need `df = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')`,  `print (df)` or `df = dataframe.join(dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).to_frame().T.rename({'row':0})).ffill()`, `print(df)`. Do you see difference? `df=` vs `dataframe['pc'] = ` ?

Comment: Or in another words - you cannot assign to new column, because errors or `NaN`s.

Comment: dude you killing :) when i print the variable than it gives an output. 
but it is still not as i expected. 
when i do `pde = dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
        print (pde)` than i get 
     `a         b
0  0.1  0.089233
1  0.5  0.092600
2  0.7  0.095815`
so here are two values missing

Comment: when i do 
`pdf2 = dataframe.join(dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).to_frame().T.rename({'row':0})).ffill()`
i get the `[6235 rows x 23 columns]` instead of only the percentile collumes. 


I need to assign the values back in to a dataframe.

to simplyfy thing we could do on percentile per line like:
like `dataframe['p1'] =dataframe['row'].quantile([.1]).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')` 
next one 
 `dataframe['p2'] =dataframe['row'].quantile([.5]).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')` 

etc. indeed my problem is to get the values back in to the dataframe

Comment: Hmmm, I forget for main question. If input dataframe is `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'row':[2,0,8,1,7,4,5]})
print (dataframe)` what is expected output?

Comment: the expected output is one row with only the values of the percentile
like:
`01       0.12344
......
6230    0.109072
6231    0.109400
6232    0.108726
6233    0.108726
6234    0.108726
Name: close, Length: 6235, dtype: float64`

Comment: OKI, can you add values instead `10`?  `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'row':[2,0,8,1,7,4,5], 'expected':[10,10,10,10,10,10,10]})` ?

Comment: unfortunalty not there is already a dataframe where i have to pull the values from and calculate the percentile on and than push it back on to a new row

Comment: Please modify your dataframe by expected output, because I dont understand what you need.

Comment: ok there is a Dataframe with many columns like open, close, cci, etc.
now i want to calculate the percentiles on the close column.
Ussaly it work like this i do a new dataframe collumne like:
`dataframe['x'] = something ` this works perfectly i get one value per row.
now when i do exactly the same thing with the `dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['close'].quantile([.1,.5,.4,.75,.8])` i get only Nan this is the issue

Comment: when i do `dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['close'].quantile([.1,.5,.4,.75,.8]).reset_index(drop=True)` i get at least the first 4 rows but than only Nan

Comment: OK, I try explain problem. If use `a = dataframe['close'].quantile([.1,.5,.4,.75,.8])` it return array with same legth as `[.1,.5,.4,.75,.8]` - so `5`. And column `close` have `7` rows (`dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'row':[2,0,8,1,7,4,5]})`). So there is logical problem - how get `5 items array` to `7 items array`, because each new column have `7 values` ? It is imposible - only solution is `5 values + 2xNaNs` for `7` values. So it is reason whay I need what you need instaed `10` in `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'row':[2,0,8,1,7,4,5], 'expected':[10,10,10,10,10,10,10]})`

Comment: i see, thanks so much for taking the time to help me figure this out. 
But my question remains:
Let say we do:
`dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['close'].quantile([.1])` and `dataframe['pc2'] = dataframe['close'].quantile([.5])` What i want is one percentile on each row from the close column. Than i should have an equal amount of in and outputs no? Or where is my error although with the other things it works as well.

Comment: for example:
`dataframe['ema3'] = ta.EMA(dataframe, timeperiod=3)`
output of this is:
`Name: ema3, Length: 6235, dtype: float64`
not a single NaN

Comment: output:`0            NaN
1            NaN
2       0.099719
3       0.099359
4       0.099180
5       0.098140
....
6233    0.108857
6234    0.108792`
ok first two are Nan because ema3 need a minimum of 3 values to be calculated

Comment: but is is difference between it, quantile dont return array with same size as original, but different size :(

Comment: Also I test `dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['close'].quantile([.1])` and it return `NaN`s (correctly). Or need `dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['close'].quantile([.1]).iloc[0]` for full scalar column with same value?

Comment: Duuuude i think that's it. 
when i do `dataframe['pc'] = dataframe['close'].quantile([.1]).iloc[0]`
i get the full list  so no NaN anymore now only one last thing the value is now for each row the same: `0       0.089233.
...
6234    0.089233
Name: pc, Length: 6235, dtype: float6`

If we manage now to have for each column the actual corresponding value from the same row in the close column than it is perfect.
So percentile in row 0 shall be the percentile of column close row 0

Comment: So `pdf2 = dataframe.join(dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).to_frame().T.rename({'row':0})).ffill()` does not work?

Comment: yes it does but i takes now all columns not only the close one. Output:`[6235 rows x 22 columns]`

Comment: Unfortunately if you cannot give me your expected output in `dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'row':[2,0,8,1,7,4,5], 'expected':[10,10,10,10,10,10,10]})` I dont know :( It seems I still dont undersntand what you need :(

Comment: ok so 
`dataframe['pc'] = pd.DataFrame({'close'].percentile[.1]`
should result in `expected':[percentile of column close row 0,percentile of column close row 1,percentile of column close row 2, etc.]}`

Comment: Do you need `pdf2 = dataframe[['row']].join(dataframe['row'].quantile([.1,.5,.7]).to_frame().T.rename({'row':0})).ffill()` ?

Comment: ok its still not exactly like expected but your answers where very good anyways!